# Python List to Pandas DataFrame with Number & Strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a following list (this list need the separator for each comma);

```
[(5461, '1.20', 'A', 'BR SK-EL 7 EP', '146', 'E', 52, 0)]
```

And also another list;

```
['A',
 'B',
 'C',
 'D',
 'E',
 'F',
 'G',
 'H']
```

How can i get this desire output with python?

```
A      B     C   D              E    F   G   H
5461   1.20  A   BR SK-EL 7 EP  146  E   52  0
```

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution if data are list of tuples:

```
data = [(5461, '1.20', 'A', 'BR SK-EL 7 EP', '146', 'E', 52, 0)]
cols = ['A', 'B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
print (df)
      A     B  C              D    E  F   G  H
0  5461  1.20  A  BR SK-EL 7 EP  146  E  52  0
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in data], columns=cols)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[x for x in data]], columns=cols)
```

Comment: No, it' s not working. I got this; ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (1, 8). Need to separate "data"  list from each comma, i guess.

Comment: I still get this error;  Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (1, 8).

Comment: I checked and both of is list like this exactly; data = [(5461, '1.20', 'A', 'BR SK-EL 7 EP', '146', 'E', 52, 0)]                                                                               
['A',
 'B',
 'C',
 'D',
 'E',
 'F',
 'G',
 'H']

Comment: @Salih - added to answer check of types and check of data, what return `print (type(data[0]))

print (type(data[0][0]))

print (data[0][0])` for you?

Comment: Type is <class 'pyodbc.Row'>

Comment: <class 'pyodbc.Row'>
<class 'int'>
5461

Comment: @Salih - Can you check `df = pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in data], columns=cols)` ?

Comment: @Salih - Or `df = pd.DataFrame([[x for x in data]], columns=cols)`

Answer (score 1):

Lets explicitly prepare list of data

```
s = [(5461, '1.20', 'A', 'BR SK-EL 7 EP', '146', 'E', 52, 0)]
l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
data = [(list(s[0]))]

pd.DataFrame(data, columns = l)



Out[90]: 
          A     B    C              D    E  F   G  H
      0  5461  1.20  A  BR SK-EL 7 EP  146  E  52  0
```